# How to access my wallet with a mnemonic phrase in mycrypto.com desktop app?

Tags: wallets

So here is the case:

I downloaded mycrypto.com desktop app and created a mnemonic phrase there. After typing in the phrase it allows to choose a wallet from many different wallet numbers (addresses 0x..). So I chose one and transferred 1 eth onto it.

Now when I type in the mnemonic phrase again, the wallets I am offered to choose from are different from the one initially and of course have zero balance.

The transaction went on smoothly and there are more than 40 confirmations

How can I access that particular wallet now?

Comment: so the solution was to not type the password in together with the mnemonic phrase (I probably didn't set one)

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so it can help others in similar situation.